# How many number of virtual users available with PVU license for load testing with RPT?

Tags: automated-testing, performance, load-testing

I have two questions:

1. I am using RPT(IBM rational performance tester) as **standalone** application. That is, not along with following  offerings:

   ```
   IBM Rational Performance Test Server
   IBM Rational Test Virtualization Server
   IBM Rational Test Workbench
   ```

   I want to ask can I use PVU licensing for virtual users in RPT installed as a standalone application?
2. In virtual tester pack there are predefined number of virtual users available in that pack. But how many virtual users are available with PVU license?

Answer (score 1):

You can launch the Installation Manager and modify your RPT install options to add PVU support.  The following link describes that setup - it looks like your particular situation applies under option 1.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21902683

As far as how many virtual users you can take advantage of, that depends on your CPU.  The PVU licensing only applies the number of virtual users that your processor can support and still give you valid results.  However, you will have to check your license agreement or with your IBM rep to see if you can apply your license as PVU.  See this link for more info about licensing, including PVU.

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBLQQ_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.rtw.install.doc/topics/c_license_descriptions.html#c_license_descriptions__licenses_pvu